# applying Watson's lemma to an integral

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-transform, laplace-method

Let $\lambda>-1;{\color{red}{\mu}}\in\mathbb{R};0<T\leq\infty, g(0)\not=0$. Watson's lemma is basically the ${\color{red}{\mu}}=0$ version of the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{T}t^{\lambda+i{\color{red}{\mu}}}g(t)e^{-xt}\mathrm{d}t
=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{g^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\frac{\Gamma(\lambda+i{\color{red}{\mu}}+k+1)}{x^{\lambda+i{\color{red}{\mu}}+k+1}}
+O\left(x^{-\lambda-N-2}\right),\quad\text{ as } x\to+\infty\tag{1}
\end{equation}

I verified (1) by slightly modify the proof for Watson's lemma in wikipedia.org.

***question (1)*** where can I find a reference for the proof of (1)?

***question (2)*** how do I apply the original Watson's lemma to the following integral?

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{1}(1-t)^{\nu+i{\color{red}{\mu}}}e^{-xt}\mathrm{d}t
,\quad\text{ as } x\to+\infty\tag{2}
\end{equation}

If I set $\lambda=0,g(t)=(1-t)^{\nu+i{\color{red}{\mu}}}$ and use the binomial expansion formula
\begin{equation}
(1-t)^{\nu+i{\color{red}{\mu}}}=1-(\nu+i{\color{red}{\mu}})t+O(t^2) \qquad \text{ as } t\to 0^+\tag{3}
\end{equation}
then I obtain:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{1}(1-t)^{\nu+i{\color{red}{\mu}}}e^{-xt}\mathrm{d}t
=\frac{1}{x}-(\nu+i{\color{red}{\mu}})\frac{1}{x^2}+O(x^{-3})
\qquad \text{ as } x\to+\infty\tag{4}
\end{equation}

If ${\color{red}{\mu}}>x$, then $|\nu+i{\color{red}{\mu}}|/x>1$. Thus (4) is divergent.  This is the problem I encountered.  How to make it convergent?

Thanks-
mike